# Yii CList view update is throwing "page not found"?

Tags: yii

I have a CListView in a view as follows:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
  'id'=> 'recentBuyers',
  'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
  'itemView' => '_buyingHistory',
  'summaryText' => '', 
));
```

I have a button that will increase the number of buyers on this List. The problem is, once that operation completed successfully, I execute this:

```
$.fn.yiiListView.update("recentBuyers"); // refresh recent buyers
```

When this executes I can see the little progress circle turning, but after a few seconds there is a popup that throws this error:

```
Page not found
```

My original thoughts were that you might have to provide a second parameter that includes what you want to update. But I don't really want it to be updated with data, but rather REFRESHED.

Question 1: How do I do that?

Update: My suspiciouns are now that I possibly am not updating the $dataProvider. The $dataProvider variable is populated as follows:

```
$condensed = array_splice($data->buyers, 0, 5);
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider ($condensed);
```

Where $data is pumped into the view via the Controller:

```
$this->render('view', array('data' => $buyers ));
```

Question 2: Do I somehow have to update  this variable before calling the Javascript?

Comment: What do you mean under increasing the number of buyers on the list? Increasing a limit of displayed buyers per page from 5 to, say, 10?

Comment: I have a button. When you click it, it does an action that increases the number of buyers in the database. I want javascript that will update this list after I've added more buyers in the database. The list is linked to the buyers in the database, so I just want to automatically update this List?

Comment: When `$.fn.yiiListView.update("recentBuyers");` check URL path into firebug's console or chrome's network panel

Comment: It says: GET http://localhost/b4a/www/buyers/view/2-open-yes?ajax=recentBuyers 404 (Not Found)

Comment: And what are the route (`controller/action` pair) and the URL of your controller's action that renders the list on the page? As I can see from JavaScript code of `yiiListView` the same URL with appended `ajax` parameter is used to update the list. So then your action's URL must be http://localhost/b4a/www/buyers/view/2-open-yes Seems to me that `2-open-yes` cannot be an original action's name so probably you use some rules for URL manager, don't you?

Comment: its is buyers/view ? And yes, I use a url manager. Basically this exists:  localhost/b4a/www/buyers/view/2-open-yes .. but this doesn't localhost/b4a/www/buyers/view/2-open-yes?ajax=recentBuyers ... I have a rule that allows me to grab "2-open-yes" as the path name for the specific buyer being viewed. Does that helpl?

Comment: paste your urlManager config, that should help in answering this

Comment: Yes, probably the issue is in URL manager's rules. Though I had no luck to reproduce your problem. I'm not sure whether I get your business logic but supposing that some `id` GET-parameter is your `2-open-yes` and having  `'buyers/view/<id:[A-Za-z0-9-]+>' => 'buyers/view'` as a rule of URL manager everything works for me - `CListView` successfully updates through ajax request. Please update your question with URL rules and also by the relevant part of your `buyers/view` action if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Open calling page with firefox + firebug installed

Open firebug

Click on .NET and on 'XHR' filter

Then click on the link/button/ or what else is and read the complete url your code is calling

or controller/action doesn't exists

or simply the name of the parameters are differentes from action signature...